# Summary of data from a data frame

Tags: r, data-mining, dataframe

I have another question concerning data mining from a large data frame that Im working with, the first few lines are as follows:

```
      Assay   Genotype   Sample    Result
1     001        G         1         0
2     001        A         2         1
3     001        G         3         0 
4     001        NA        4         NA
5     002        T         1         0
6     002        G         2         1
7     002        T         3         0 
8     002        T         4         0
9     003        NA        1         NA
10    003        G         2         1
11    003        G         3         1 
12    003        T         4         0
```

In total I'll be working with 2000 samples and 168 Assays for each sample.

Id like to generate a summary table from this data that tells me how many 'Samples' have each 'Result'. There are only 3 options for 'Result' 1, 0, or NA. I would like the result to have a data frame that looks like this (using the above data):

```
Assay    1   0   NA
001      1   2   1 
002      1   3   0
003      2   1   1
```

As I mentioned above there are 168 different Assays and they are not simply labeled in a numeric series, so the Assay ID must be extracted from the original data frame.
In an ideal world, I would also like to see a percentage of samples for each 'Result' listed next to the numbers (or in a different table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
table(df$Assay, df$Result,useNA="ifany")
```

Comment: This is close but only tells me the number of 1 and 0 but not the number of NA.

Comment: Pretty fast update (+1). Anyway, I will not delete my very similar answer as I think keeping the headers is more elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

Like @MYaseen208 but adding NA column:

```
> table(df[, c('Assay', 'Result')], useNA='ifany')
     Result
Assay 0 1 <NA>
    1 2 1    1
    2 3 1    0
    3 0 0    1
```

See: `?table`